# How to search for files in Terminal using indexed list?

Tags: command-line, gnome, search, tracker, indexing

If I want to search for files in Terminal, I tend to either use something like `tree --prune -P <searchTerm>`, but this can take a long time with a big directory so when it's too big I tend to revert back to the GUI (even though this is something I don't like doing very much) in order to use Nautilus's ability to use the file index (as files are indexed to increase the efficiency of the search).

But I don't like having to do this, so I was wondering if there is a way of searching through a certain directory and all of its sub-folders for files using the item index created by tracker like can be done through the GUI (I have only said 'files', but I would also like the search results to include folders)?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `locate` while updating the database every 30 minutes (subsequent updates take far less time than the initial).

**crontab entry**

```
*/30 * * * * /usr/bin/updatedb
```

If you're working in any of the *pruned* directories, you would need to modify `/etc/updatedb.conf`.  Or if you were only working in for instance /home/user, you could add directories to omit, and speed up updating the database.